# Efficient way to crop a strip of a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, java-2d

I want to remove a strip (widthways) of an image by moving the top part of the image to the bottom. Currently I'm doing this but I think that maybe there is a more efficiently way to achieve this without creating a new BufferedImage.

Snippet code:

```
BufferedImage myImage = ...;
...
BufferedImage imgPart_1 = myImage.getSubimage(0, 0, myImage.getWidth(), (myImage.getHeight()/2)-50);
BufferedImage imgPart_2 = myImage.getSubimage(0, myImage.getHeight()/2, myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight()/2);
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics g = newImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(imgPart_1, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(imgPart_2, 0, imgPart_1.getHeight(), null);

myImage = newImage;
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new Image, but you don't have to paint it yourself.

You can use the [CropImageFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/CropImageFilter.html) to get your image.

```
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    CropImageFilter cropFilter = new CropImageFilter
            (x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    Image croppedImage = toolkit.createImage(new FilteredImageSource
            (image.getSource(), cropFilter));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty efficient to me: are you really sure there is a performance problem here?

If you really want to avoid creating a new bufferedimage, you can use myImage as the destination, i.e. just do:

```
Graphics g = myImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(imgPart_1, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(imgPart_2, 0, imgPart_1.getHeight(), null);
```

I think this will work OK in your case, although you will need to test (there can be some odd effects when the source and destination areas are overlapping!)